# Como podría validar un dato tipo bool en Entity Framework, lo correcto seria dejarlo true o false consejos

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Por ejemplo una entrada tipo string la valido con

```
If(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BD.campo) ==true)
{
      Mensaje="introduzca un dato para campo";
      return;
}
```

Esto en C# MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si necesitas que para el usuario sea obligatorio no omitir ese campo dejalo como false por ejemplo

```
if(DB.bool == false)    
{                   
    mensaje = "Active el campo para guardar";   
    return;                   
}
```

Espero te funcione...

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta veré la implementación si funciona las validaciones